# Access data from APIs like Hootsuite etc does (without user login)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've been working a little bit with APIs lately, mostly the Facebook API and now the Instagram and Twitter APIs. But one common thing about them all is how they work, in that sense that the user has to be logged into their service at that computer/web browser at the same time.

For example, if I were to make a page where you could read your Facebook feed, the user would have to create an account at my page, along with signing in at Facebook and authorizing the app. Next time, if he was using the same computer/ web browser and didn't sign out of Facebook, it would be no problem. But if he was using another computer or did sign out, he would be presented with the Facebook login.

I didn't store any data in a database of mine, everything was accessed from Facebook directly.

But services like [HootSuite](http://www.hootsuite.com) doesn't work like this. I could sign up at HootSuite one time, choose Facebook, sign in and authorize the app, and then access my feed from any computer in the world with only one login in at HootSuite. How do they do this? Do they have a special agreement with Facebook, or is this something I could learn and use myself (a service/ something that is accessible for every Facebook app developer out there)?

And what exactly do they store in a database? Do they store my Facebook username/password, or a string of data that they send to Facebook for confirmation (that I haven't revoked any permissions) without me seeing it?

Hope some of you know this, it's quite interesting.

Comment: @Kiquenet I was not able to replicate the effect HootSuite gives sadly. I stopped working on it a while ago, but it is a very interesting topic and I might return to do some more "research" at some point later in time. Until then, refer to Sushant Guptas answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi, I am currently developing for hootsuite and seeing that nobody has answered your query yet, I would try to provide you some insight.

Hootsuite has internally used developer apis provided by LinkedIn, facebook, Twitter and other social networks. There is a documented approach to use these apis. generally, it involves creating an application(here, a hootsuite app) on these social networks. This app has an id of its own on these networks. When you create an account on hootsuite, it asks you to add your social network accounts.

When you click a social network name, an access request is sent by the hootsuite app to the selected social network. The destination social network first validates your app id(in this case, hootsuite), then it authenticates the user credentials(username and password) and then presents you with an authorization screen what data fro your profile would you want the hootsuite app to access.

This information is now condensed an object containing these authorization parameters alongwith an oauthaccess token is sent back to the hootsuite website. These oauth tokens have a lifetime(e.g. linkedin access token lifecycle is 60 days), which means it is valid for 60 days.

The hootsuite never stores your (twitter, facebook, etc. networks)username or password, it stores the oauth token value and repeatedly uses whenever you use hootsuite.
So an oauth token is unique to your social network account plus hootsuite account, which acts like a superpass to read your data.

That's my analogy. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the feedback!

I have a couple of more questions to you: I'm developing an app myself which has some Facebook integration. It does the same as HootSuite (sends an request, receives an OAuth token etc), but the problem is that I have to be signed in to Facebook at the same time on the same computer. Let's say I log off Facebook, and then enter my app. I'll be presented with the Facebook login screen, to login to FB. When I use HootSuite, I can be logged off on Facebook, but still see my feed at HootSuite. How do you guys do that?

Comment: Hootsuite saves the oauth token key and oauth token secret sent by facebook and uses in subsequent requests. This is how they do it.

Comment: Alex, if my answer was of help, please do mark it as answered. :)

Comment: @SushantGupta, How is Hootsuite able to search users for Facebook? Is there an open API for this from Facebook?